# How to iterate and loop through every array value in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, request

```
    while True:
        for i in range(len(listing_ids)):
            response = requests.get(f'apiurl/{listing_ids[i]}/pr', cookies=cookies, headers=headers) 
            response = response.json()
            print(response['jsonValue'])
            break
```

I have an array currently as `listing_ids` and within this array has an undetermined count of values that I want to use within a request URL then price the response then loop back through until the the last value within the array was used. How can I format this? Currently it just infinitely loops with the 1st value ONLY

Comment: Remove the `break` statement to loop through all values in the for loop and not stop after the first. Not sure you need the `while` loop either from what you describe, you're just looping over a list?

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement in your code breaks the `for` loop after it's first iteration, then because the `while` loop is still running the `for` loop starts all over again. Step-by-step what's happening is:

1. The `while` loop starts its first iteration
2. The `for` loop starts its first iteration
3. First request is made for the first id
4. First JSON value is printed
5. `break` is executed - start from step 2 again

If I understood your intent correctly you can just remove the `while` loop and the `break` statement. Your code will then iterate over the list and make a request for each id.